# Wordpress login attempts with personalized data

Tags: wordpress, authentication, hacking

I recently got some login attempts on a self-hosted Wordpress site that make me a little bit nervous: The login attempts are non-standard usernames like "admin" or "root". They used a username from a person of the website. This person's mail address doesn't appear on the website.
Are there any automated attacks known that use for companies mail addresses and use it for login attempts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the user has created some pages or posts, perhaps their username is displayed

Comment: No, it's a OnePager site. There is no user account named like the person with the failed login attempts. So it's not possible that there are blog posts in the name of the person. I searched the source code but no hits with the name with the failed login attempt.